# How to get loop index items not divisible by 2

Tags: nunjucks

If I have the following loop setup...

```js
    {% for items in Reviews %}
            {% for client in items.feedback %}
               <div class="{{"bg-grey-light" if loop.index % 2}}">
                  <p>{{client.message}}</p>
                  <p>&mdash; {{client.name}}</p>
               </div>
            {% endfor %}
         {% endfor %}
```

..I can easily get by `bg-grey-light` class appearing on every other div. But how do I check if my loop index "is not" divisible by 2?

I read [this official guide](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#logic) and attempted to use not in my case like so....

```js
  {% for items in Reviews %}
            {% for client in items.feedback %}
               <div class="{{"bg-grey-light" if not loop.index % 2}}">
                  <p>{{client.message}}</p>
                  <p>&mdash; {{client.name}}</p>
               </div>
            {% endfor %}
         {% endfor %}
```

But no luck.  It throws an error and says..

> "Error: pushToken: can only push one token on between reads"

Many thanks in advance for the help

Comment: could you not just use css? :nth-child(even) {...}

Comment: Thanks! I'll take that as answer too.  I totally overlooked CSS on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check when the mod is 0 vs when it is 1. You are currently implicitly checking loop.index % 2 == 1, to get the opposite you can check loop.index % 2 == 0:

```
{% for items in Reviews %}
    {% for client in items.feedback %}
    <div class="{{"bg-grey-light" if loop.index % 2 == 1}}">
        <p>{{client.message}}</p>
        <p>&mdash; {{client.name}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

vs

```
{% for items in Reviews %}
    {% for client in items.feedback %}
    <div class="{{"bg-grey-light" if loop.index % 2 == 0}}">
        <p>{{client.message}}</p>
        <p>&mdash; {{client.name}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```